# Load order of included Javascript scripts

Tags: javascript

My JS/HTML app is loading some controllers which I have set up as included object literals:

e.g.: page1Controller.js

```
var page1 = {
  initialize() {
    $(".page").removeClass('on');
    $("#page1").addClass('on');
  },
  doThis: function() {
    // script here
  },
  doThat: function() {
    // Script here
  }
}
```

e.g.: navigation.js

```
var navigation = {
  bindEvents: function() {
    var page1Button = document.getElementById('page1Button');
    page1Button.addEventListener('click', this.loadPage1, false);
  },
  loadPage1: function() {
    page1.initialize();
  },
  loadPage2: function() {
    page2.initialize();
  }
}
```

note: navigation.js.bindEvents() gets run after pageLoad/deviceLoad event (it's a phonegap app).

and the scripts are included at the bottom of my HTML page as:

```
<script src="page1Controller.js"></script>
<script src="page2Controller.js"></script>
<script src="page3Controller.js"></script>
<script src="page4Controller.js"></script>
<script src="navigation.js"></script>
```

It is my understanding that as a default, the scripts will be loaded synchronously - one after the other in the order they appear in the HTML page.

However, when I call say page3.doThat() from navigation.js, the doThat function is undefined, although functions within some of the other controllers work fine. Is it the case that, even though the scripts are loaded in order, navigation.js might be loaded up before page3Controller.js has 'registered' it's functions fully?

Comment: *"It is my understanding that as a default, the scripts will be loaded synchronously - one after the other in the order they appear in the HTML page."* That's correct. With the markup and code in your question, there is no way code in `navigation.js` could fail to see a filled-in `page1` object assuming that's at the top level of `page1Controller.js`.

Comment: Perhaps your code in `page1Controller.js` and such *isn't* at the top level? Perhaps it's only run in response to an event, like `onDOMContentReady`?

Comment: maybe, you should use window.onload or document.onload or you can use setTimeout with check function.

Comment: can you post the full content of **page3Controller.js**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code is definitely at the top level. page1Controller.js is only ever invoked from a function within navigation.js. In the real code, an initialize() function hides all 'pages' (Divs in an SPA) in the DOM and makes it's own pertinent div visible. So navigation.js would call page1.initialize() for instance. In the top level of navigation.js I can log page1.initialize to the console *and* I can log it directly from a browser console.

Comment: @ZigZag - can't really include the actual code for NDA reasons, hence the silly names for the scripts, sorry.

Comment: It's up to you to produce a [mcve] of the problem. Without one, the question cannot be answered. The problem is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Point about NDA should have been @oliv37 apologies. I have fattened out the code above a bit to hopefully make it a bit nearer to my actual code setup.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Solved! navigation.js was being called via a callback which led to it no longer being in scope. My original question asked If my assumptions about script order was correct, which is why I posted 'made up' code. I needed to know if my assumptions were correct and then I could troubleshoot my code based on that. If you can post your "That's correct..." comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the accepted answer as you actually did answer my question. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! I think the topic of script load order is probably already well-covered here on SO, so probably best to just delete the question. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder. Not sure I agree though. I could find plenty of help that showed the order of loading vis a vis a HTML page, but nothing that made the point you just made above, "there is no way code in navigation.js could fail to see a filled-in page1 object assuming that's at the top level of page1Controller.js". That was significant for me and I didn't see it covered anywhere else. But it's up to you if you want to put that as the answer. If not, I'd prefer to answer it myself and have it here for others.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that in the case of scripts loaded in order in a set of HTML script tags, each script is loaded in its entirety into memory, before the following script, making functions in earlier scripts accessible to ones called later. Thanks to @T.J. Crowder in his comments for pointing this out.